# Replace all 0 values with 1 in dataframe with multiple rows and columns at once

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

How can I replace all NA, NaN, 0, 0.00, 0.000 values with 1 in dataframe with multiple rows and columns at once? Thanks.

An example df:

```
a = c(233, 0, NA, 3455)
b = c(23, 0.000, NA, 345)
c = c(223, 0.00, NaN, 30055)

df = cbind.data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Comment: It's very helpful to provide data if you'd like help more quickly. That said, check out `dplyr::mutate_all` , as I think that should provide you a quick solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you provide an example input dataset and desired output dataset?  Can you be more specific about "etc"?

Comment: I have updated my question with a simple example. I can replace column-wise but my actual dataframe has hundreds of columns and thousands of rows!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like @zack's suggested [`dplyr::mutate_all()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html).  Another option is [`purrr::map_df()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).

```
scrub <- function( x ) {
  x <- dplyr::if_else(dplyr::near(x, 0), 1, x)
  x <- dplyr::coalesce(x, 1)
  x
}

# Option 1 (These four lines are equivalent):
df %>%                                  # This needs `library(magrittr)` 
  purrr::map_df(scrub)
purrr::map_df(df, scrub)
purrr::map_df(df, ~scrub(.))
purrr::map_df(df, function(x) scrub(x))

# Option 2, suggested by @zack in the comments:
dplyr::mutate_all(df, scrub)
```

Here is the result from `purrr::map_df()`, which is a [`tibble`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/).  The `dplyr::mutate_all()` returns a [`data.frame`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html).

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   233    23   223
2     1     1     1
3     1     1     1
4  3455   345 30055
```

Comment: @zack, for the sake of completeness, I included your `purrr::map_df()` suggestion from three days ago.  I'm happy to remove it if you submit a separate answer.